# jQuery: Change dropdown select when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, forms, select, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have this form:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="First" />First
<input type="checkbox" value="Second" />Second
<input type="checkbox" value="Third" />Third

<select name="first-drop">
    <option value="---">---</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

​Is there a way (using JS/jQuery) I can change the value of `first-drop` to `---` whenever the `First` check box is unchecked?

Comment: Those two paragraphs have two totally different meanings. Do you want to hide or change the value?

Comment: Change the value. Fixed the question, sorry about that confusing bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][value="First"]').change(function (){
    $('select[name="first-drop"]').toggle();
});​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8QwMB/1)

Note that I fixed you markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="First" checked="checked" >First
<input type="checkbox" value="Second" />Second
<input type="checkbox" value="Third" />Third

<select name="first-drop">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
</select>​
```

---

**Update:**

What you want now is:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][value="First"]').change(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $('select[name="first-drop"] option:first').prop('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

**[​LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8QwMB/2)**

If you will give your DOM elements ids it can be simple as that:

```
$('#first').change(function() {
    if (!this.checked) 
        $('#nothing').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

**Updated DOM:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="First" id="first" >First
<input type="checkbox" value="Second">Second
<input type="checkbox" value="Third">Third

<select name="first-drop">
    <option value="" id="nothing" >---</option>
    <option value="Option1" >Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
</select>​
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8QwMB/3)**

Comment: Thank you for the markup fix! My problem is more of changing the selected value of the dropdown when the checkbox is unchecked, rather than making the dropdown disappear. My wording might be misleading, I'll revise it.

Answer (score 2):

I added an ID to the first checkbox

```
<input id="first" type="checkbox" value="First">First</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="Second">Second</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="Third">Third</input>

<select name="first-drop">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">$Option2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#first").click(function () {
            if ($(this)[0].checked == true) {
                $("[name='first-drop'] option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
            }
        });
    });​
</script>
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8BtYc/2/

**Edit: Fixed my code so that it doesn't toggle when you uncheck the first checkbox**